# VARCHAR2 column formatting in spool file

Tags: sql, oracle11g, formatting, spool, varchar2

I'm working on an assignment and the spool output is getting some weird formatting for VARCHAR2 function returns. The class uses Oracle SQL 11g.

I have this PL/SQL script:

```sql
SET echo on
SET wrap off
SET trimspool on
SET linesize 80
SET colsep '|'
SET serveroutput on

spool @assignment.txt

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dollar_fmt_sf(
    p_num NUMBER
)RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    lv_amt_txt VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    lv_amt_txt := to_char(p_num, '$99,999.99');
    RETURN lv_amt_txt;
END;
/

SELECT
    idbasket,
    dollar_fmt_sf(shipping),
    dollar_fmt_sf(total)
FROM
    bb_basket
WHERE
    idbasket = 3;

spool off
```

This produces an output like this in assignment.txt where the last two columns are on separate lines.

```
  IDBASKET
----------
DOLLAR_FMT_SF(SHIPPING)                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOLLAR_FMT_SF(TOTAL)                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         3
                                                                           $5.00
                                                                          $32.40
```

I would like to have it look more like this with the headers on the same line:

```
  IDBASKET|  SHIPPING|     TOTAL
----------|----------|----------
         3|         5|      32.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your table so I'll use Scott's `emp` sample table for that purpose.

Function is *as is*:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dollar_fmt_sf(
  2      p_num NUMBER
  3  )RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  4      lv_amt_txt VARCHAR2(20);
  5  BEGIN
  6      lv_amt_txt := to_char(p_num, '$99,999.99');
  7      RETURN lv_amt_txt;
  8  END;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * from bb_basket;

  IDBASKET   SHIPPING      TOTAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7499        300       1760
      7521        500       1375
      7654       1400       1375
      7698                  3135
      7844          0       1650
      7900                  1045

6 rows selected.
```

Query - as you said - doesn't look OK:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      idbasket,
  3      dollar_fmt_sf(shipping),
  4      dollar_fmt_sf(total)
  5  FROM bb_basket;

  IDBASKET
----------
DOLLAR_FMT_SF(SHIPPING)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOLLAR_FMT_SF(TOTAL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      7499
    $300.00
  $1,760.00

      7521
    $500.00
  $1,375.00
<snip>
```

---

What to do? Set **alias** to columns returned by function calls and **format them**:

```
SQL> col shipping format a15
SQL> col total format a15
SQL>
SQL> SELECT
  2      idbasket,
  3      dollar_fmt_sf(shipping) as shipping,
  4      dollar_fmt_sf(total) as total
  5  FROM bb_basket;

  IDBASKET SHIPPING        TOTAL
---------- --------------- ---------------
      7499     $300.00       $1,760.00
      7521     $500.00       $1,375.00
      7654   $1,400.00       $1,375.00
      7698                   $3,135.00
      7844        $.00       $1,650.00
      7900                   $1,045.00

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Looks better, doesn't it? Include that into your script (where all those `SET`s are).

Comment: One more thing: maybe you'd want to consider modifying format model to $99,990.00; result might look *prettier*.